# Ruby: What happens when I delete element of an array when iterating over the same array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am iterating over an array using for, and when a certain condition is met, I need to delete the current element from the array. Is this a safe operation?

```
for arrayElement in array1 do
    if (arrayElement < min) then
         array1.delete(arrayElement)
    end
end
```

Or, should I modify my code to perform the deletion outside the for block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not safe. Do not change underlying container while you iterate it. This could cause unexpected behaviour.

For example, following code causes infinite loop:

```
a = [1]
a.each { a.push 1 }
```

---

You code can be written using [`Array#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
array1 = [5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 7, 8]
min = 4
array1.delete_if { |arrayElement|
    arrayElement < min
}
array # => [5, 4, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is unsafe operation, because iterators usually don't expect collection to change underneath them. Depending on the implementation (of iterator), you will get some elements twice (or more) or will not see some elements at all.

You should iterate (or modify) a copy, not the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing context of what `min` is, but have you considered using the delete_if method?

ex: `array1.delete_if { |x| x < min }`

From http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if :

> Deletes every element of self for which block evaluates to true.
>
> The array is changed instantly every time the block is called, not after the iteration is over.